# regression on 2d vector in r

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, model

Trying to do a simple regression on a 2d vectors. I don't think this is the right way.

vec1x=  c(0.4191, -0.0064, -0.1071,  0.0605, -0.0290)

vec1y=  c(8.0054,  5.7876,  6.9907,  7.9606,  8.8073)

vec2x=  c(2.5424,  5.1469,  4.7073,  4.3420,  6.7717)

vec2y=  c(1.1129,  2.6307,  1.7691,  0.3857, -1.6576)

vec3x=  c(1.8899,  3.7936,  4.3746,  2.7874,  1.3930)

vec3y=  c(9.6567,  7.4949,  6.7109,  6.9061,  8.7460)

REG=glm(c(vec3x,vec3y) ~  c(vec1x,vec1y)+ c(vec2x,vec2y))

but when I run the X  and Y separately I get different beta (I should?).

Is there another type of regression I can use that can take care of this 2d?
Im new to this stuff.

Comment: I think you need to expand this to clarify what your scientific question is. It is not at all surprising to me that you get different results splitting the data so we need to see why you felt otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

For simple linear regression, you should use the "lm" (which stands for linear models of which simple linear regression is one type) function rather than the "glm" (which stands for generalized linear models). The way to do this is to 
 1. Put all your Xs in a matrix and Ys in a vector
 2. Combine the X and Y into a Data Frame (this is Rs default way or organizing statistical data. It seems weird and you could think of it as a matrix with some very descriptive labels)
 3. run the lm function on the dataframe.

For examples see:
https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/63893_9f6bc9cd73ad47aab3aa85d0193244d9.html

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation, I just wanted to put up some code to make sense, I am actually using a dataframe. The thing is my dependent variable is has coordinates of x and y same with the regressors. would you know what type of model can handle this?

Comment: Sorry. I am not clear about what you are trying to say. Are you saying that there is a spatial aspect to your regression problem?